# Why can't I find/search some files in Windows 8?

Tags: search, windows-8-preview, windows-search

Why can't I find, via a search, some files in Windows 8? I've checked and unchecked all the usual boxes like shown below.

[image]

and

[image]

but it still wont find it. I'm looking for the file "idapi32.cfg" in c:\program files(x86)\borland\common files\BDE. I can browse to it and see that its there. Why can't Windows 8 see it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably not an [indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexing_Service) location. You can change the Windows 8 Indexing options to include `C:\Program Files(x86)\` or any other file location under the Windows Indexing settings.

You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for Run and then insert `control /name Microsoft.IndexingOptions`.

You can also get to this menu from `Control Panel -> Indexing Options`

From there Select `Modify` and add the desired path

Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-indexing-options.htm)

Comment: @Brandonkreisel Can you please explain why indexing is sometimes important to find files? I was just able to search for files that were in locations that were not indexed.